# Event Registration - Avoid Member Discount

Tags: cividiscount

For an event, a member can register multiple people. However when there is a member discount, this discount gets applied to everyone the member is signing up for. Is there a way so that only the member gets the discount but not the others!

Thanks :)

Sri